# What do the different colors of my fleets' firepower mean in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

In Stellaris, my fleets' firepower amounts are listed under their location in the Outliner window in yellow. I assume this is the default font color for the UI.

However, one of my fleet's firepower label is listed in red, and there's no indicator or tooltip explaining the difference in color. I don't think the guided tutorial <strike>slave</strike> robot covered this, either.

Why is one of my fleet's firepower labels showing up as red?

[image: Military Fleets and their respective firepower labels; one is shown in red]

To provide a bit more information, my 3rd Fleet is comprised of 14 Corvettes. My 1st Fleet, by comparison, has 12 Corvettes and 1 Cruiser. I don't recall the ship breakdown of my 2nd Fleet at the moment.

Originally, I surmised that the red color coding was because my 3rd Fleet was executing a combat order/was in combat, but I saw the red number even when the relevant fleet was not in combat or heading toward combat, which rules out that theory.

Comment: The missing information about your 2nd Fleet is found in the Fleet Manager screen.  Current composition only effects the fraction's numerator and the fleet power.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The red fleet power number is telling you that the fleet in its current state is significantly below the power of its template in the Fleet Manager.  This can be because either the fleet needs upgrading or reinforcing.  The Up arrow to the left of the fleet power indicates that you could use an upgrade.

Your "1st Fleet" on the other hand can also use an upgrade, but as its 14 size is greater than its template's size "(13)", its fleet power is at least that of its template.

I'd need to see more information to explain why your "2nd Fleet" of size 13 has at least the fleet power of its size 15 template.

---

The new Fleet Manager is a very cool tool.  I definitely recommend you get comfortable using it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. The number in parentheses is the number of actual physical ships in the fleet, while the fraction number is the number of ship 'slots' used up (out of a total of 30 slots per fleet (due to the new admiral limitation in 2.0 to combat doom stacks)). Perhaps the color coding of the numbers in parentheses refers to what you are talking about. At any rate, I will add some extra information about my fleet breakdown to the question.

Comment: @TylerH My point is easily proven.  Open the fleet manager and press the +/- buttons on any design.  You'll see the number in parenthesis move about without the expenditure of a single mineral. So the format is "<current command usage>/<fleet command limit> (<template's planned usage>)

Comment: Hmm, then I wonder what the different colors of the parenthetical number indicate. The 2nd Fleet, if I recall correctly, consists of 10 or 11 ships I built, and 2 or 3 pirate ships that defected and joined my empire. They could be stronger individually and thus make up the difference.

Comment: @TylerH Ahh!  Ships you didn't design or can't produce, can't be accounted for in the Fleet Manager!  If they significantly out-tech your current situation, that would explain your 2nd Fleet being short on ships but good on power.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. I have some salvaged cruisers from the gas giant event and they appear in my fleet make-up in the fleet manager. Normally, they don't have +/- buttons, but the fleet manager screen still seems a bit buggy. I've uncovered a few UI issues under certain conditions. I also managed to convince the fleet manager to build some salvaged cruiser ships at the fleet's home shipyard.

Comment: Finally had time to fire up Stellaris and confirm this. It would be awesome to see a screenshot of the Fleet Manager with a specific tooltip or two active describing this added to the answer if possible.